# Alternative to gnome-screensot

Tags: linux, screenshot

Is there an alternative to gnome-screenshot (in Ubuntu) to take screenshots that are automatically saved in a specif directory and that no message is shown every time one presses the Print Screen key?

I remember that in Fedora this was possible with the default screenshot program. Was it the same program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Workaround to use gnome-screenshot without the save dialog box

`gnome-screenshot` has an `-f` option to save a screenshot directly to a specific file. The following command should be the replacement you are looking for:

```
gnome-screenshot -f "$HOME/Pictures/Screenshot from $(date '+%F %T').png"
```

One way is to revise `gnome-screenshot` to be run with an additional parameter:

1. Move the original gnome-screenshot executable file:

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.orig
   ```
2. Create a modified command in gnome-screenshot.mod by editing it in nano text editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.mod

   #!/bin/sh
   gnome-screenshot.orig -f "$HOME/Pictures/Screenshot from $(date '+%F %T').png" $@
   ```
3. Make it executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.mod
   ```
4. Create a replacement symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.mod /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
   ```

<sub>**Source:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/497199/is-there-a-setting-to-turn-off-the-dialog-box-when-making-screenshots/497399#497399</sub>

#### Software recommendation

Sometimes I need to capture a complicated area of screen real estate and no matter what I do gnome-screenshot doesn't capture the image I wanted, because when I click to take the screenshot a dropdown menu on the screen that I wanted to capture disappears from view in the window that it belonged to.

Shutter (*shutter*) from the default Ubuntu repositories is a more full-featured screenshot application than the default gnome-screenshot application. Shutter can do everything that gnome-screenshot can, and it has the additional advantage of being able to capture dropdown menus and other GUI items that are visible to the eye on the screen, but the GUI item disappears from view if you try to capture it and the window that it belongs to with gnome-screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

[scrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot) lets you save a screenshot to a specified directory, and doesn't show a message. It has a nice command-line interface, so setting it up is a matter of binding your preferred command string to the Print Screen key.